# how to add cite paper in Springer?

Tags: bibliographies

I want to add some cites in Springer journal paper in the following way, but it never works. namely: **? ?**

Tex file

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
%

%\documentclass{svjour3}                     % onecolumn (standard format)
%\documentclass[smallcondensed]{svjour3}     % onecolumn (ditto)
\documentclass[smallextended]{svjour3}       % onecolumn (second format)
%\documentclass[twocolumn]{svjour3}          % twocolumn
%
\smartqed  % flush right qed marks, e.g. at end of proof
%
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{natbib}


\begin{document}

\citep{Hvala}, \citep{Birkenmeier}

\bibliographystyle{spbasic}
\bibliography{litera}   % name your BibTeX data base



\end{document}
% end of file template.tex
```

Bib file

```
@article{Hvala,
    author = {Hvala, B.},
    title = {Generalized derivations in rings},
    journal = {Comm. Algebra},
    volume = 26,
    pages = {1147--1166},
    year = 1998,
}
@inproceedings{Birkenmeier,
    author = {Birkenmeier, G. F. and Heatherly, H. E. and Lee, E. K.},
    title = {Completely prime ideals and radicals in Near-rings},
    booktitle = {Proceedings of Near-rings and Near-Fields},
    publisher = {Kluwer},
    year = 1995,
    pages = {63--73},
    editor = {Fong, Y. and others},
}
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: You should compile with : `pdflatex`, `bibtex` and then `pdflatex` twice... Did you?

Comment: Mhhh, the example works for me if I compile it with the usual cycle LaTeX, BibTeX, LaTeX, LaTeX (https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864). Do you get any errors or warnings when you run LaTeX or BibTeX? Can you attach the `.blg` file?

Comment: @koleygr sure, I have ....

Comment: @moewe .blg file This is BibTeX, Version 0.99dThe top-level auxiliary file: template.aux
The style file: spbasic.bst
Database file #1: litera.bib

Comment: If it says nothing more that is a good sign. After two additional LaTeX runs the example should give the expected output. Does the LaTeX run throw additional errors or warnings? Can you check that the `.bbl` file contains a `thebibliography` environment and two `\bibitem`s?

Comment: I think you could try compiling on overleaf.com (at least if you already have an account there) in order to see if this a problem of your installation. May be @moewe already run your code with this documentclass, and thus this proposal will not be important. But if not, a test would convince us that something is wrong with your installation or with your compilation commands

Comment: @koleygr it does not work in TexitEasy Editor... but works in another editor

Comment: Probably it is an Editor specific problem then... But I haven't even heard about that editor.. So I could not help you... (Changing editor to something more standard would be a solution)